# How to change the icon of a C# WinForms exe, in TaskManager

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, taskmanager

I've already set the icon in the Project Properties, and the FormControl Icon.
I've thus got my icon (`.ico` file) in:

- The TaskBar.
- The TaskTray.
- The top-left of the Form.
- In Windows Explorer, if I navigate to the exe on disk.

But I've still got the default icon in TaskManager:

[image]

**How do I fix that, in my C# WinForm?** (i.e. make the icon in the red circle look unique, like VS, Excel, Firefox, etc. all do)

(There are a few answers that appear to address this in C++, but nothing in C#-land, or WinForms.)

Comment: How did you set your icon?

Comment: See fsbflavio's answer for how I initially set the Form Icon, and the Application Icon. It turns out that DOES change the TaskManager Icon, you just need to reopen TM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dammit.
It turns out the answer is "close and re-open TaskManager".
It must have cached the icon.

Restarting the exe didn't help, but restarting TaskManager sorted it.